# What DLLMain lpReserved parameter really mean?

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, internals

One of well-known [DLLMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function parameters is *LPVOID lpvReserved*.
From MSDN documentation:

> If fdwReason is DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, lpvReserved is NULL for dynamic
>   loads and non-NULL for static loads.

But what lpReserved really mean?
Is pointer to somenthing?

Comment: A quick Google search [reveals a few others who have wondered about this and sought to find out](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=127), but do keep in mind that all such information is for curiosity purposes only. The only information you can *rely* on is that which is given in the documentation.

Comment: Formulate comment as answer I accept it. I overlook this link, perhaps I have bad day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quote in the question contains all the information that you are permitted to rely on:

> If fdwReason is DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, lpvReserved is NULL for dynamic loads and non-NULL for static loads.

All you are entitled to do is treat `lpvReserved` as a boolean that signals information about whether the load is dynamic or static (aka implicit).

It's perfectly plausible that there are versions of Windows for which `lpvReserved` carries more information that a plain boolean. However, that is a private implementation detail and you should not rely on that.